# Column Specific Update Trigger not working properly

Tags: triggers

I am trying to use a SQL Server trigger to update a column and insert a new row in table B based on an update in table A but having issues with update trigger firing when I update other columns in Table A despite specifying the column.  I am using an Azure SQL Database on SQL Server.

Context:

1. In Table A, I have a StageID that users will update with values 1-16. (See Screenshot)
2. Table B is a historical table that keeps track of how long a user stays in a particular stage.
3. I have built an update trigger that is specific to updating column StageID.  If the StageID is  updated, it will find the record in Table B and put a Stage End Date on the previous record and insert a new record with the new stage and a null Stage End Date
4. Users will be updating one record at a time

[TableA](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IUboC.png)
[TableB](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bK5Eg.png)

Issue:

1. Even though I have specified the column when the trigger should fire for an update, it will fire if I update other columns in Table A and give me extra history records for that StageID

[Issue with Extra Recs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2KeiU.png)

Ideal State:

1. I would like for the Update trigger to fire only when the StageID is updated in Table A and no other columns
2. See data example of what my history table should look like

[TableB](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bK5Eg.png)

Please note that I am not a DBA or anything close to it (as you can tell by my code below).  I would just really like to get ideas on the best way to resolve this and frankly, I'm not tied to using a trigger, I just don't know another way to update the StageID in Table A and put historical records in Table B without one. Any help would greatly be appreciated and thanks in advance!

```
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
ALTER TRIGGER [dbo].[UpdateAdjStatus]
ON [dbo].[AdjudicationDetails]
AFTER UPDATE AS
BEGIN 
    DECLARE
        @AdjudicationID NVARCHAR (200),
        @StageID INT,
        @ContractID INT,
        @Modified_By NVARCHAR(100)
        
        SELECT @AdjudicationID = INSERTED.[AdjudicationID],
        @StageID = INSERTED.[StageID],
        @ContractID = INSERTED.[ContractId],
        @Modified_By = INSERTED.[Modified_By]
        FROM INSERTED

    IF ( UPDATE ([StageID]))
        BEGIN
          UPDATE [dbo].[AdjudicationStatusDetails]
          SET [Stage End Date] = CAST(SYSDATETIMEOFFSET() AT TIME ZONE 'Central Standard Time' AS date)
          WHERE AdjudicationID = @AdjudicationID
          AND [Stage End Date] IS NULL
       
          INSERT INTO [dbo].[AdjudicationStatusDetails] (AdjudicationID, StageID,[Stage Start Date],[Stage End Date], [Created_Date],[Created_By],[Modified_Date], [Modified_By],[ContractID])
          VALUES (@AdjudicationID, @StageID, CAST(SYSDATETIMEOFFSET() AT TIME ZONE 'Central America Standard Time' AS date), NULL, 
          CAST(SYSDATETIMEOFFSET() AT TIME ZONE 'Central Standard Time' AS date),@Modified_By, 
          CAST(SYSDATETIMEOFFSET() AT TIME ZONE 'Central Standard Time' AS date),@Modified_By,
          @ContractID);
        END
END;
```

Comment: Your trigger has **MAJOR** flaw in that you seem to assume it'll be called **once per row** - that is not the case. The trigger will fire **once per statement**, so if your `UPDATE` that causes this trigger to fire updates 25 rows, you'll get the trigger fired **once** and the `Inserted` and `Deleted` pseudo tables will contain 25 rows each. Which of those 25 rows will your code select from `Inserted`? It's non-deterministic, you'll get **one arbitrary row** handled, and all others will be **ignored**. You need to rewrite your trigger to take this into account!

Comment: @marc_s - Thanks for the feedback.  What is your suggestion to have the trigger fire only when a specific column is changed and not fire when other columns are edited in the same row? I thought that using the IF UPDATE() was supposed to rectify that but it did not.  Any thoughts?

Comment: You need to do it in a **set-based** manner - link up the `Deleted` and `Inserted` pseudo tables via the primary key, check if the `StageId` column has changed, and for those rows where it has, run the update and insert statements. All in proper, set-based fashion - with `JOIN` etc. - do **NOT** select values from tables - that won't work properly ....

Comment: @marc_s - That is SO helpful - I really appreciate it.  Sorry to ask but would you happen to have a basic example (or pseudo code - Frankly I'll take anything at this point)?  I think if I can see the basic structure of what the code looks like I can adapt it to what I need. Many Thanks!